# Can CMake terminate a parallel build if any thread fails?

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I'm running CMake with `-Wfatal-errors`, which correctly terminates compilation for the first error it encounters. However, in parallel builds, all the other non-failed threads keep going until they finish their current job (i.e. finish building whatever file they were on). Is there a way to get CMake to also kill these child compile processes if any one of them fails?

Comment: AFAIK, `make` does not have such functionality. You could use Ninja as a build generator with `-G Ninja`. Ninja has this behaviour by default; from Ninja'a help page `-k N  keep going until N jobs fail [default=1]`.

Comment: @compor, I think `-k` does not kill already running jobs, which OP wants. At least ninja 1.10.2 does not.